# show a message 60 days before a specific date

Tags: php

i want show a message 60 days before a specific date.

i have made this script:

```
$current = date("Ymd"); // this is the current date 20162306

$time = strtotime($row3["data_scadenza_arbo"]);

$notify = date('Ymd', $time); // this is the date inside the db (is 20162322)
```

I converted my dates in numbers, but I do not know how to move forward.

Comment: What kind of message are you trying to show? What libraries are you using? Are you looking to show a message _now_ which tells the user what that date is? Are you looking to show a message _if_ today is that special date? Are you looking to show a message _if_ today is _after_ that special date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use DateTime

You better use DateTime class do manipulate and compare dates:

- [DateTime documentation](http://php.net/datetime)

I came up with a little snippet for you:

```
<?php

$current = new DateTime();

$notify = new DateTime($row3["data_scadenza_arbo"]);

$difference = $current->diff($notify);

var_dump($difference->days); // remaining days (integer)
```

- [DateTime::diff() documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

Answer (score 0):

this can helps you, you may need some flag if the notification was not already sent.

```
if(strtotime($date_from_db) > time()-(60*60*24*60)) sendNotification();
```